# Is the function $\alpha$ an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V = \mathbb{Q}[X]$ and to each vector $v = [b_1, b_2, . . .] \in  \mathbb{Q}^{\infty}$ assign a linear functional
$\delta_v \in D(V)$ defined by $\delta_v: \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nX_n \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n! a_n b_{n+1}$. Is the function $\alpha : \mathbb{Q}^{\infty} \to D(V)$ defined by $v \mapsto \delta_v$ an isomorphism?

I suspect that I will have to show that $\alpha$ is both monic (one-to-one) and epic (onto) to show that it is bijective, but I am not sure how to accomplish that.

Any ideas/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check that $\alpha$ is linear, so showing it's injective reduces to showing that $\delta_v = 0$ implies $v = 0$.

Comment: @JoelCohen thanks for the advice. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @DerpMagoo Any ideas?